# How to reference .dll that in different solution from the main solution visual c++ 2008?

Tags: visual-c++, dll

i found a guide that showed how to reference .dll files to the main project, if it is in the same solution but i didn't find something that shows how to do this with two different solutions

Comment: Why not add the project to the second solution as well?  That or just add a reference to the binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is somewhat helpful. Good Luck!!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84deabaa-ae82-47cc-aac0-592f5a8dfa22/linking-an-external-dll